# How to login as another user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

In my Laravel app I've two type of user: user A and user B. In a page of user A I have all the users B detail that I showed in a `<table>`. In a column of this table I have a button that when user A press it, he should see in a new tab of the browser the main page of the user B. I found on the Laravel documentation the method `Auth::loginUsingId()` but I don't understand where I put it on my controller or route or blade file. So what I have to do?

Comment: It'd go in a controller, and you'd have the button execute that controller's route (possibly via AJAX, or a form post). There are ready-made plugins for this (that will helpfully handle things like *undoing* the impersonation): https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate

Comment: Laravel has the ability to setup multiple guards and multiple user providers.  You can configure two different guards such as `web`(the default) and `admin`. When you want to login as the other user: `Auth::guard('admin')->loginUsingId(1)`